# Where do 覚悟なさい、我慢なさい come from?

Tags: verbs, conjugations

The more common 「覚悟しなさい」 and 「我慢しなさい」 seem also much more intuitive: 覚悟する➞覚悟しなさい

覚悟なさい、我慢なさい seem to be feminine markers. How did they come about?

Comment: Well, なさる is itself the 尊敬語 of する (though I wouldn't describe なさい as 尊敬)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

意味は同じになるのですが、「我慢しなさい」の「なさい」と「我慢なさい」の「なさい」は、文法的にちょっと異なるもので、

「しなさい」= 動詞「する」の連用形「し」+ やわらかな命令を表す補助動詞「なさい」
「なさい」= 動詞「なす・する」の尊敬語「なさる」の命令形

なので、

「我慢しなさい」は、サ変動詞「我慢する」の連用形「我慢し」+ やわらかな命令を表す補助動詞「なさい」

「我慢なさい」は、サ変動詞「我慢する」の「する」が尊敬語「なさる」に、更に命令形「なさい」になったもの

のように考えてはどうでしょうか。

「～なさい」のほうは、「～しなさい」よりも、少し古風な、より丁寧な、やわらかい感じがします。そのため、男性よりも女性に使われることが多く、女性的な響きがあるのかな、と思います。